# awk print output as variable/array not staying formatted

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

My aim is to take the output from an awk print command (while keeping the formatting) and use that to replace certain text in a file.
Currently im using:

```
declare -a mach=($(awk -F',' 'NR>1{print NR-1, $8}' mag_grad.csv))
```

which gives:

```
1 0.77492
2 0.18022
3 0.29596
4 0.5229
```

etc...

I'm trying to use sed to find and replace text in a file with the array $mach, with the same formatting of 2 columns.

```
sed -i s/"mach data"/"${mach[*]}"/g nodedata.txt
```

However the result of this is to replace mach data with

```
1 0.77492 2 0.18022 3 0.29596 4 0.5229 .......
```

Any ideas on how I could preserve the formatting?

Cheers

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?  Do you want to preserve the newlines in the output?  If so, why are you using an array which will split everything and remove all whitespace?

Comment: I'm very new to any kind of scripting, so I apologize if I'm using things wrong.

yeah I want to preserve the new lines in the output, thought I had to set it as an array, instead of a variable. However whenever I try and use sed with mach as a variable not array it doesnt replace the word with the correct data, just the word "mach"

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
mach=$(awk -F',' 'NR>1{print NR-1, $8}' mag_grad.csv)
sed -i "s/\x22mach data\x22/${mach//$'\n'/\\n}/" nodedata.txt
```

Comment: tried this and it just replaced "mach data", with the word mach, not the variable mach unfortunatley

Comment: I'd use perl for this: no problems with newlines in the replacement text: `perl -i -pse 's/mach data/$data/g' -- -data="$mach" filename`